# View questions voted to close

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

There seems to be not that many people with all out permissions to close (with moderator tools I think @ 10k ?), is there anyway to view a list of questions that have been voted to be closed, like the "Review" tag, or is this taken care of by the people with the privileges?

Just thinking about some clean-up and all the unanswered Q's.

Comment: I often close vote stuff, but until I get 10k+ rep it's a long way (not too hard pushing to get there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only moderators have binding close vote.

Close overview is included in [10k moderator tools](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools).

Comment: Yes I understand but there are only 4 members with over 10k, do you guys get a notice on "close" flagged questions?

Comment: Rarst - push @Wyck Question.

Comment: @kaiser mods get actively notified of flags. Close votes are votes, not flags - so need to go and look for them in tools.

Answer (score 2):

The [/review](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/review) pages have seen a lot of improvements lately, and most relevant to this discussion is that there's a new tab for questions with close votes.  You can filter by the number of pending close votes as well as the reason.

Comment: I don't see this tab you speak of. I presume you need 10K rep to see it? If that's the case I don't think that's right. We have very few people with the ability to close vote, it would help those that do have the ability, to have visibility of what questions have close votes, so they can add theirs to hopefully get the question to 5 close votes.